# What are the steps needed to enable a Chrome extension to do screen sharing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, remote-desktop, remote-access, screensharing

Google offers the Remote Desktop extension, which allows remote control of a desktop.

However, if all we want is to allow screen sharing from a Chrome extension, what are the APIs we should look at?

The ideal workflow:

- Bob starts screen sharing from a Chrome extension.
- Alice can see Bob's screen by visiting a specific URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [`SCREENSHARING A BROWSER TAB IN HTML5`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/#toc-method3), you can easily get this accomplished.

Start by

1) Creating a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)

2) Use [`Tab's API`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) to capture screen

3) Use Binary `WebSocket` to transfer information over wire .

### References

- [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)
- [Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab)
- [HTML5 Article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/#toc-method3).